# I get a 404 error when trying to upload using multer node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, multer

I am in the process of coding a website in node.js which will allow a small advert to be created with various information, and images to be uploaded. The data is stored in a mongodb database which works find, however when i try to upload images using multer i get a 404 error stating that /api/photo cannot be found.

this is my app.js
http://pastebin.com/f7x6Kjq8

and this is my add_advert.jade which is where the buttons are which drive the code. It is the 'Upload Images' button which is failing

http://pastebin.com/kw9aUVTQ

It is probably something very obvious that I am missing but I have been racking my brain for hours trying to work it out!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) especially [Help Center > Asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Here you can see `[...]also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time.[...]`

Answer (score 3):

I have managed to find a solution to my issue! it was because of where the upload functions were placed. They must be places after the 'app.use' functions where routes are called in